# Why doesn't simplifying this limit work?

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to find the following limit:
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin x^2}{\sin x^2+x^2 \cos x^2}\right)$$
I simplified it by dividing by $\sin x$, and I got
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2 \tan \left(x^2\right)}\right)$$
which is equal to $1$.

However, my book states that the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, and L'Hopital's theorem is used to find the limit.

What is the mistake in my method?

Comment: Does $\sin x^2$ mean $\sin^2x$ or $\sin (x^2)$?

Comment: That should be $\cot$, not $\tan$.

Comment: Dividing by $x^2$ might make it easier. If you know limit of $\sin x / x$

Comment: Since you've got something of the form $\lim_{x\to0}f(x^2)$, I would have started writing that as $\lim_{x\downarrow0}f(x)$, just to save some typing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Properly:

$\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{\sin(x^2)+x^2\cos( x^2)}=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2(\cos(x^2)/\sin(x^2))}=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2\color{blue}{\cot(x^2)}}.$

Answer (score 4):

Good idea -- just a trig error -- $\sin(y)/\cos(y) = \tan(y)$, but you've got a cosine over a sine in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\frac{\sin (x^2)+x^2 \cos (x^2)}{\sin (x^2)}\\ =1+{x^2\over \sin (x^2)}\cos (x^2)$$ Puttng in the limit $1$ for $\sin(u)/u$ as $u\to 0$ (with $u=x^2$), the limit of this expression at $0$ is equal $2,$ hence its reciprocal tends to $1/2.$